# How to get notification from sever if process on specific port is interrupted

Tags: server, notification, process

I am new to Ubuntu and would like to know if there any command or package available for the issue I'm facing.

Issue:

I'm running some process on specific port on Ubuntu server, the system is being used as production resource. Now when process is interrupted or down, we don't know until client starts reporting issues. So, we would like to have solution which will send us notification or mail if the process has issues and its not running.

**Edit**

1. What version of Ubuntu?

Ubuntu 16.04 server

2. How do you start the process?

using command like

```
geth --nousb --datadir=$pwd --syncmode 'full' --port 30310 --miner.gasprice 0 --miner.gastarget 470000000000 --http --http.addr 'localhost' --http.port 8545 --http.api admin,eth,miner,net,txpool,personal,web3 --mine --allow-insecure-unlock --unlock "wallet-address" --password password.txt
```

When you run the upper command, it will create an ipc (Inter-process communication)

3. Does "interrupted or down" mean frozen? Crashed?

Yes, I used interrupted word for both, either down or frozen

4. Is it responsive to input at your end?

It's actually blockchain service, and I connect it with node js API. so, not directly responsive for the input.

5. Does it end itself? Or do you need to kill it before restarting?

We have created the service that will automatically restart the service after X seconds if the process is not running. However, I suspect the case where process was running and when I try to connect IPC (`geth attach geth.ipc`) it refused and showed the error "process is already in use". In that case I need to kill the service force fully and restart again.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? How do you start the process? You could set up a `cron` job using `pgrep` or `lsof -i tcp:xxx` (where `xxx` is the port #). Read `man pgrep lsof cron;man -a crontab`.

Comment: Does "interrupted or down" mean frozen? Crashed? Is it responsive to input at your end? Does it end itself? Or do you need to kill it before restarting?

Comment: Thanks! @waltinator I have updated the question with required detail. I will look into `pgrep or lsof -i tcp:xxx`

Comment: Thanks @user535733 I have updated the question with required detail.

Comment: Seems like you have a trigger (*it refused and showed the error "process is already in use"*). Use that trigger to generate the notification that you need.